# Quoting shell commands

Tags: listings, typography

My question is, how would you typographically approach quoting of shell commands? My current solution does not satisfy me completely.

Current look:

[image: current look]

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? What doesn't satisfy you about the current look?

Comment: Well, but which is your current approach? Besides the image of the result, it would be good to know the current *code* you are using.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that shows your current code.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on suggesting alternatives.

Comment: Hey, since the matter is not regarding code, but purely typographic approach towards the issue, I do not believe it is necessary to include code. I am fine with purely code-less suggestions for the solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use the `listings` package, with the `sh` language. You can then say e.g. `\lstinline!for i in $(seq 0 10); do echo "Now $i"; done!` inline and get it (reasonably) typeset. Or include complete scripts, with the same typography.

Other "typeset programs" packages might be useful too, I'm just used to `listings`. Rummage around in CTAN.

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed helpful. I will gladly see more ideas though!